# How to stop a Thread (and foor loop) - java

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, progress-bar

I initializing a thread that updates a progres bar, inside the thread I have the for loop to update the progress bar, 
 this part works fine, but......on the app i have a button to cancel, is possible to stop the thread(and the for loop),

with what I have now on my logs I see STOP THREAD, but the progress bar keeps upding the content;

```
 Thread myThread =  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
            Log.e(TAG, "HERE");
            for (int progress = 0; progress <= progressMax; progress+=4096) {

                notification.setProgress(progressMax, progress, false);
                notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build());
            }
            notification.setContentText(text)
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false);
            notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build()); 

         }
    });
    if (value == 2000) {
        myThread.start();

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "STOP THREAD");
        myThread.interrupt();
        notification.setContentText(text)
                        .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a flag to mark if cancelled. And do check-and-quit inside the for-loop. Set the flag to true when cancel button pressed.

```
for (int progress = 0; progress <= progressMax; progress+=4096) {
    if(quit_flag) {
        // do some clear work
        return;
    }
    notification.setProgress(progressMax, progress, false);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build());
}
```